# If T: $L^p(R) \to L^q(R)$ is linear and continous, and $T(L^p(R))$ is in $C_b(R)$ as sets, show that T: $L^p(R) \to C_b(R)$ is linear and continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

If T: $L^p(R) \to L^q(R)$ is linear and continous, and the image of  $T(L^p(R))$ are in $C_b(R)$(the set of continous and bounded functions)  as sets, show that T: $L^p(R) \to C_b(R)$ is linear and continuous with the sup norm on $C_b(R)$

I thought that if a function is in $L^q(R)$, then it is either bounded or the set that is unbounded has measure zero anyway, so $L^q(R)$ and $C_b(R)$ are not exactly that different, but a function in $C_b(R)$ probably is not in $L^q(R)$ unless it is some kind of rapidly decreasing function so we end up with a finite integral, but I am not sure what kind of functions are in both
$L^q(R)$ and $C_b(R)$ such that we know these functions have some definite properties.

Also, how can we show the mapping T is continuous with the $C_b(R)$ sup norm which is quite different than the $L^q(R)$, because in order to show T is continuous( or bounded since T is linear), we need to find a bound of some kind to compare a function with $L^q(R)$ and the same function with $C_b(R)$ norm, but I currently no clue on how to do that.

Comment: This smells like an application of the closed graph theorem.

Comment: @gerw oh that's interesting. What makes you say that?

Comment: In most cases such "automatic continuity"-results are an application of the closed graph theorem.